# Alternative Characters - HackerRank

Tags: c++, c++11

I am beginner, alternative to this code is most welcomed. 
Program crashes after inputing the values.
I also want to know more about this problem, since i have seen it many time.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
vector<string> str;
int n,i=0,count=0,a=0,b=1;
string j;

cin >> n;

while(i<n)
{
    cin >> j;
    str.push_back(j);
    i++;
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    while(b!='\0')
    {
        if(str[i][a] == str[i][b])
           {
             count++;
           }
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}

cout << count;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: would you please tell me what does your program intend to do? what output you want from this program after inputting n number of strings?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w10/challenges/alternating-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your strange program to work you should do three things:
set init values to `a` and `b` on every external loop step;
change `b!='\0'` condition to `str[i].c_str()[b]!='\0'` in order to check not `b`, but string literal;
call `string::c_str()` method on your strings, because it is not guaranteed that string will be null-terminated, only c-style strings stand this condition.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    while(str[i].c_str()[b]!='\0')
    {
        if(str[i].c_str()[a] == str[i].c_str()[b])
           {
             count++;
           }
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following loop never ends.

```
while(b!='\0')
{
    if(str[i][a] == str[i][b])
       {
         count++;
       }
    a++;
    b++;
}
```

You end up accessing `str[i]` beyond valid indices.

```
while(b!='\0')
```

is equivalent to

```
while(b != 0)
```

You start with `b = 1` and keep on incrementing it. Hence, the conditional in the while loop will always be true.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
while(str[i][b] != '\0')
```

Also, you have reset the values of `a` and `b` after the `while` loop. Otherwise, they will continue from the values of the previous string and you will end up using indices that are not correct. Here's one way to fix that. Create them in the nested scope of the enclosing `for` loop.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    while(b!='\0')
    {
        if(str[i][a] == str[i][b])
           {
             count++;
           }
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}
```